# Best way to handle empty values in mysql columns

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a large CSV file with 10 million rows and 20 columns into a table in MySQL. A lot of the values that would otherwise be INTs, BIGINTs, TIMESTAMPs or FLOATS have empty values.

For instance:

```
mysql> SELECT ID,LinkedAccountId FROM billing_info WHERE LinkedAccountId = '' LIMIT 10;
+---------+-----------------+
| ID      | LinkedAccountId |
+---------+-----------------+
| 9323504 |                 |
| 9323505 |                 |
| 9323507 |                 |
| 9323509 |                 |
| 9323527 |                 |
+---------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (18.69 sec)
```

Should I always assign CHAR or VARCHAR to an empty column like the one above? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: This is one of the main scenarios NULL is intended for in databases.

Comment: Just leave them as NULL, no need to complicate things with (posible) casting and messing around.

Comment: Ok. So would you guys recommend I run an update query to change the empty fields into NULL? NULL is completely different from empty text as in `LinkedAccountId = '';` correct?

Comment: A numeric field like that really should not be a data type that allows it to be `''`.

Comment: I agree. I wanted to determine the best way to handle this, I'm new to doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If very few rows includes the column and size is sparse, you can break out those columns with a 1-1 relationship, e.g. a column with ID and LinkedAccountID, and then left join that table to retrieve values. As each value would occupy two columns (ID and some value), this could be worth it if for instance less than 10% of rows contains a certain column. It would be especially useful if covariance exists between missing columns (if LinkedAccountID is missing, 2 more columns are also always missing), as you could break out all of them to the same table.

In other cases you'd probably be better off just using null values.

Comment: There's actually a TON of empty text values throughout the CSV files. So it would be better to run an update query to change them into NULL values?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that is a more clear way to represent it. Just watch out for null pointer exceptions in the code that reads from the database.